holoviews/panel plot not updated when executed in Jupyterlab
In a jupyterlab cell, I am trying to update a plot figure from an external data source which does not know about the figure.
But I cannot manage to have the figure updated during the cell execution as the data source is updated. Instead, my figure is updated only once at the end.
Here is the test code sample:
import matplotlib as mpl
import panel as pn
from IPython import display
import holoviews as hv
import time
pn.extension()

val = 0
stream = hv.streams.Stream.define('I', index = 0)()

# This is the callback that is called whenever I push data in my `stream`
# This writes "HELLO {i}" in a matplotlib figure where `i` is the data updated
def _cb(index):
    mpl.pyplot.ioff()
    fig = mpl.figure.Figure(figsize=(1, 1))

    string = f"HELLO {index}"
    print(string)
    fig.suptitle(string)
    
    mpl.pyplot.ion()
    panel = pn.panel(fig)
    return panel

# Create the panel widget
col = pn.Column(pn.bind(_cb, index=stream.param.index))
display.display(col)

# Regularly publish data in my stream
for i in range(10):
    stream.event(index=i)
    time.sleep(1)
print("end of loop")

What I expect

When creating the figure and calling display.display, I shall see the figure created.
When calling stream.event in my for loop, I should see the above figure updated every 1s, at the same time I should see "HELLO {i}" in the logs

What I observe

My figure is correctly created and displayed
The logs appear below the cell, but the figure is not updated (keeps on "HELLO 0")
When the cell finishes, I see the log "end of loop" and the figure is updated with "HELLO 9"

Note 1
When running only the for loop in a second cell, the figure of the first cell is correctly updated every second.
This does not match my final use case as all the code should be executed in one cell, but I'd like to understand what happens.
Note 2
When running this cell in vscode with Jupyterlab extension, vscode first complains about not having jupyter_bokeh and after installation and kernel restarts, it behaves as expected (regular updates of the figure).
Running in jupyterlab with a kernel containing jupyter_bokeh does not work though.
Do you now if jupyter_bokeh might be related to this issue?
My configuration
holoviews                     1.18.3
ipython                       8.18.1
ipython-genutils              0.2.0
ipywidgets                    8.0.6
jupyter_bokeh                 4.0.5
jupyter_client                8.6.0
jupyter_core                  5.7.1
jupyter-events                0.9.0
jupyter-lsp                   2.2.4
jupyter_server                2.13.0
jupyter_server_terminals      0.5.2
jupyterlab                    4.1.3
jupyterlab_pygments           0.3.0
jupyterlab_server             2.25.3
jupyterlab_widgets            3.0.10
jupytext                      1.16.2
matplotlib                    3.7.5
matplotlib-inline             0.1.6
panel                         1.3.8

Thanks for your help!

So I see this comment, "# This writes "HELLO {i}" in a matplotlib figure where i is the data updated". Is that because that step/code works elsewhere, separate from Holoviews / Panel plot when you comment out some other stuff? Or you have wrapped things in Matplotlib to add interactivity and hopefully control Holoview/panels? First Matplotlib shouldn't need to be involved here? (See here & note the original post and answer don't involve Matplotlib. Matplotlib is capable of doing this or Holoviews/panel is capable. But these are entirely...

 separate packages that would be best not to mix & match.)So maybe that is leftover? And if you were trying to use interactivity with Matplotlib, I think you are consulting old approaches and code. You need to install ipympl and use %matplotlib ipympl at the start of your cell, see here for more about that. That is the classic symptom of not using ipympl correctly where you get it running but just get the last frame showing, which is what I take you mean by, "Instead, my figure is updated only once at the end..

You are probably right, in the end I don't really need interactivity, but mostly update a figure asynchronously. Your point is that I should display hv.Image instead of matplotlib.Figure?

I know you are trying to say you don't need interactivity per se, yet 'updating', like animation ability, falls under interactivity in the matplotlib world, at least. I don't know exactly why the current ipympl documentation fails to point this out. The FuncAnimation function of matplotlib needs it. However, yes, I am trying to say I don't think you need Matplotlib at all for what you want to do. Because you you seem to be more relying on that toolset, you should stick to holoviews/Panel/bokeh, which don't need matplotlib.
